# When Scroll in table view timer reset to original value in tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, timer, tableview, reset

I have list of job (table view) and when I click on any job it means I applied to job and then timer start (30 seconds countdown) within this I can undo may applied job. I have seperate timer on each cell.
I used 2 sec timer fuction for reloading table view.

Cell for row code is given below:

```
 if data.current_state != 1{
        if data.isApplied == true
        {
                if cell.countdowlLbl.text != "00:00" || cell.countdowlLbl.isFinished != true
                {
                    cell.applyBtn.isHidden = true
                    cell.appliedUiView.isHidden = false
                    cell.AfterAppliedView.isHidden = true
                }    
                else
                {
                    data.current_state = 1
                    cell.applyBtn.isHidden = true
                    cell.appliedUiView.isHidden = true
                    cell.AfterAppliedView.isHidden = false
                }
            }else{
                cell.appliedUiView.isHidden = true
                cell.applyBtn.isHidden = false
                cell.AfterAppliedView.isHidden = true  
            }
    }else{
        cell.AfterAppliedView.isHidden = false
        cell.appliedUiView.isHidden = true
        cell.applyBtn.isHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Please specify a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TimerCell: UITableViewCell
 {
     var timer = Timer()
      var counter = 0
     @IBOutlet weak var btnStartTimer: UIButton!
      @IBOutlet weak var lblTimer: UILabel!


func startTimer()
{
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(actiontimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    lblTimer.text = "\(timer)"
}

@objc func actiontimer() {
     counter += 1
    lblTimer.text = "\(counter)"
}
}

- Create timer with particular cell using table view cell class and start 
   timer on when select job. so, it's start only for that selected job .
- And Create all cell with different identifier like:



 tbl_Job.register(UINib(nibName: "TimerCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TImerCell\(indexPath)")
    let cell = tbl_Job.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TImerCell\(indexPath)", for: indexPath) as! TimerCell
```

Comment: When answering a question, please try not only to insert a piece of code, but also add comments to it.